# Android Socket Connection fail

Tags: android, sockets, client

I am trying to establish a connection between Android Client and C# Server .. My server is working fine except the android client is not working even after adding internet connection permission

Here is the code :

```
    private void connectSocket(String a){ 

    try { 
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.2"); 
        Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting....");

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr,4444); 
        Log.d("TCP", "C: I dunno ...");
        //String message = "1";

        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try { 
          //  Log.d("TCP", "C: Sending: '" + message + "'"); 
            out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true); 
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));                

            //out.println(message);
            while ((in.readLine()) != null) {
            txt.append(in.readLine());
            }

            Log.d("TCP", "C: Sent."); 
            Log.d("TCP", "C: Done.");               

        } catch(Exception e) { 
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e); 
        } finally { 
            socket.close(); 
        } 

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        Log.e("TCP", "C: UnknownHostException", e); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        Log.e("TCP", "C: IOException", e); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }       
}
```

And here is the Debugging Log:

```
11-15 02:41:58.040: W/dalvikvm(26839): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c352a0)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at com.example.socketclient.SocketCode.connectSocket(SocketCode.java:50)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at com.example.socketclient.SocketCode.access$0(SocketCode.java:44)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at com.example.socketclient.SocketCode$1.onClick(SocketCode.java:35)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-15 02:41:58.075: E/AndroidRuntime(26839):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the looks of it you are trying to perform networking operation on the main thread. Take a look at the log trace specially line `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

[Android Developer: Network on Main Thread Exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Always do networking on a separate thread other than main. There are different ways to accomplish that as well e.g. you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or start thread on your own.

There are several posts on SO for this and Android Developer site. Here are a few links to get you going:

[Android Developer: Connecting to the network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

[Android Developers Blog: Multithreading for performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check this link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), it is because since latest version of API, it is forbidden to perform networking operation called by the main thread, so you need to create another (background) thread to perform it instead.